# How to avoid removing values from dataframes when backtesting

Tags: pandas, back-testing

I use the backtesting.py library.
Example: https://colab.research.google.com/github/kernc/backtesting.py/blob/master/doc/examples/Multiple%20Time%20Frames.ipynb#scrollTo=Hj2hR-sidDhZ

If I run a backtest using moving averages with n1 periods, the dataframe will contain Nan values during the first n1 periods. So the strategy will actually not be backtested at the start date I initially set up.

My question is about the backtesting.py library specifically.

Comment: And what is the question, exactly? Yes, it seems the initial few steps while the indicator has no data are skipped. You can easily remedy this by padding the front with more data.

Comment: I don't think you are familiar with backtesting.py